# Upload multiple files with multer

Tags: javascript, multer

The below logic only can upload one picture at a time :

Frontend :

```
const handleSubmit = async(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const newPost = {
      userID : userID, //TODO : set userID dynamically
      description : textareaValue,
      location : selectedOption,
    }
    if (fileArray.length !== 0) {
      const data = new FormData();
      const filenames = []; // Create an empty array to store filenames

      fileArray.forEach((currentFile) => {
        const fileName = Date.now() + currentFile.name;
        data.append("name", fileName);
        data.append("file", currentFile);
        filenames.push(fileName); // Push the filename into the array
      });
      newPost.images = filenames;
      
      try {
        await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/upload", data);
      } catch (err) {}
    }
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/posts", newPost);
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (err) {}
    console.log(newPost);
  }
```

Backend :

```
// upload image
const currentWorkingDirectory = process.cwd();
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(currentWorkingDirectory, "public/images")));
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public/images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    //cb(null,  file.originalname);
    const fileName = req.body.name; // Use the filename sent from the frontend
    cb(null, fileName);
  },
});

const upload = multer({storage});
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  try {
    return res.status(200).json("File uploded successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

The above code works perfectly when I only upload a single image.

However when I started to upload multiple images, the images is not stored under my local directory and I cant even fetch on frontend.

Comment: you can directly change the name of the files in the file object from the frontend, you do not need to append it separately for every file.